# Read Bar-code scanner value through window service (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-services, usb, barcode, pointofservice

I have a bar-code scanner attached to my windows machine USB port.

Is it possible to create **windows service** which runs in background and checks if any bar-code is scanned, whenever a bar-code is scanned I want the windows service to handle it and write the input in the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mhadonis,

Currently, the PointOfService namespace require foreground processing to prevent background processes from getting unauthorized access to data.  We have received a few requests to allow background, please submit your feature request via [Developer Feedback UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?category_id=202594).

Terry Warwick, Microsoft

Comment: Thank you @Terry for the response, I have raised the appropriate feature request as stated by you.